# OpenCV find contours of close objects

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am writing a C++ Application using the OpenCV library to detect objects in images. These images look like this:
http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150311/my6uczfn.png
The upper part of the image, which is black, can be ignored.

I know, that every pixel, which is not part of a desired object, will be colored in white. What I am trying to do is to find out how many objects of interest are on an image and where they are.
Up until now I wrote the following code:

```
Mat image = imread("2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if(!image.data)
{
  std::cout << "Could not open or find the image." << std::endl;
}

Range range_rows(0, image.size().height);
Range range_columns_left(0, image.size().width);
Range range_columns_middle(image.size().width, image.size().width * 2);
Range range_columns_right(image.size().width * 2, image.size().width * 3);
Mat display_mat(image.size().height, image.size().width * 3, CV_8UC3);
Mat left(display_mat, range_rows, range_columns_left);
image.copyTo(left);

Mat classified_image;
threshold(image, classified_image, 254, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
Mat middle(display_mat, range_rows, range_columns_middle);
classified_image.copyTo(middle);

Mat cimage = Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8UC3);

Mat classified_grayscale_image;
cvtColor(classified_image, classified_grayscale_image, CV_RGB2GRAY); 
std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
findContours(classified_grayscale_image, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

for(size_t counter = 0; counter < contours.size(); counter++)
{
  std::cout << "Contours size: " << contours[counter].size() << std::endl;
  if(contours[counter].size() < 6)
    continue;

  Mat pointsf;
  Mat(contours[counter]).convertTo(pointsf, CV_32F);
  RotatedRect box = fitEllipse(pointsf);

  drawContours(cimage, contours, (int)counter, Scalar::all(255), 1, 8);
  ellipse(cimage, box, Scalar(0,0,255), 1, CV_AA);
  std::cout << "Ellipse Parameter:\t";
  ellipse(cimage, box.center, box.size*0.5f, box.angle, 0, 360, Scalar(0,255,255), 1, CV_AA);
  Point2f vtx[4];
  box.points(vtx);
  for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
      line(cimage, vtx[j], vtx[(j+1)%4], Scalar(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA);
}

Mat right(display_mat, range_rows, range_columns_right);
cimage.copyTo(right);

namedWindow("Results", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Results", display_mat);

waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

The result looks like this:
http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150311/toiy3aes.png

As you see, the classification, what is an object and what is not, is not perfect, so 2 objects are recognized as one. The classification will be improved, but something like this can happen, if those objects are very close. Even more of a problem is, when they are touching each other.
How can I do a proper object recognition in the case shown above? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got few options:

- use some filtering/thresholding method on your result image to split objects from each other. Otsu binarization should be enough in this case, alternatively you can try to use dilate operation.
- inverse your result image and than use distance transform and Otsu binarization (or some other kind o thresholding - most of them should work fine). It will make you objects smaller but will make counting them much easier.
- if you need to mark the objects as precise as possible you need to use more complicated method. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) there is an tutorial which use techniques i've described above and connected components and watershed.

Comment: I used your 2nd suggestion and in terms of counting the objects I get quite good results, thank you for the help and sorry for the late response.